# how can i remove extra space in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

How can I remove the extra space from the first line? I am new to bootstrap can someone help?

Thanks in advance. I want both the lines starting from same point but it's not so.

[image]

```
<form>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
      <h1>Number of players you want to play with:</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <select name="deals" class="form-control">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div clas="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
        <h1>Number of point difference</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><h1>
        <select name="deals"  class="form-control">
          <option value="1">5</option>
          <option value="2">10</option>
          <option value="3">15</option>
          <option value="4">20</option>
          <option value="5">25</option>
          <option value="6">30</option>
          <option value="7">35</option>
          <option value="8">40</option>
          <option value="9">45</option>
          <option value="10">50</option>
          <option value="11">55</option>
          <option value="11">60</option>
          <option value="11">65</option>
          <option value="11">70</option>
          <option value="11">75</option>
          <option value="11">55</option>
          <option value="11">85</option>
          <option value="11">90</option>
          <option value="11">95</option>
          <option value="11">100</option>
        </select></h1>
        </div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">

        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary " value="Deal" >
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap is adding some top margin to each heading. You will probably have about 20px there, and the select element by default has 0 margin around it.

Either apply a custom css to the select, to move it down to the right place, or create a class that will remove margin top from the headline, then they will match.